# CPWindow is blocked after closing CPPanel

Tags: cappuccino

I added these two outlets to my `AppController.j`:

```
@outlet CPWindow theWindow;
@outlet CPWindow thePanel;
```

`theWindow` fills the whole browser window (`setFullPlatformWindow:YES`).

Now I'm using a `CPToolbarItem` (inside a `CPToolbar` which I added to `theWindow`) performing this method on click:

```
- (IBAction)showPanel:(id)aSender {

    // ...
    [CPApp runModalForWindow:thePanel];
}
```

I've created all these UI elements in Interface Builder.

When I'm closing `thePanel`, `theWindow` seems to stuck - it is not possible to click buttons or interact with elements in `theWindow` in any other way.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you're not dismissing your panel successfully, and so its modal state remains active. Try this in the code responsible for closing your panel:

```
[CPApp abortModal];
[thePanel close];
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! I didn't now I even have to do this when not closing the panel programmatically but using the panel's default close button.